# Spring Integration chain threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-integration

I try to use Spring Integration and don't find in doc some info about chain threads. I have xml:

```
<task:executor
        id="worker"
        pool-size="5"
        queue-capacity="5"
        rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<int:channel id="inputChannel" datatype="javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="worker"/>
</int:channel>

<int:chain input-channel="inputChannel" id="someChain">
    <int-ws:header-enricher>
        <int-ws:soap-action value="${someValue}"/>
    </int-ws:header-enricher>
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="url" value="${someUri}"/>
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int-ws:outbound-gateway uri="${someUri}"
                             ignore-empty-responses="true"
                             requires-reply="true"
                             marshaller="someMarshaller"
                             interceptors="someMessageInterceptors">
        <int-ws:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="integrationInterceptor" />
        </int-ws:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-ws:outbound-gateway>
</int:chain>
```

And my question: Will all endpoints in that chain work consequentially but all in separate threads? Will gateway response and request work in separate threads? Can i use ThreadLocal for save some info in one chain endpoint and use that info in next endpoint ot that chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each component in the chain will run on the same thread.

Yes, you can use `ThreadLocal`s to convey data between components, but often message headers are used for that purpose instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need get info in Client Interceptor. it seems there i can't get integration message headers - only soap envelope. Is it true?