# How to perform a series of steps in a single thread, with an async flow in spring-integration?

Tags: spring-integration

I currently have a spring-integration (v4.3.24) flow that looks like the following:

```
           |
           | list of
           | filepaths
      +----v---+
      |splitter|
      +----+---+
           | filepath
           |
+----------v----------+
|sftp-outbound-gateway|
|        "get"        |
+----------+----------+
           | file
+---------------------+
|     +----v----+     |
|     |decryptor|     |
|     +----+----+     |
|          |          |
|    +-----v------+   | set of transformers
|    |decompressor|   | (with routers before them
|    +-----+------+   | because some steps are optional)
|          |          | that process the file;
|       +--v--+       | call this "FileProcessor"
|       | ... |       |
|       +--+--+       |
+---------------------+
           |
      +----v----+
      |save file|
      | to disk |
      +----+----+
           |
```

All of the channels above are `DirectChannel`s - Yup, I know this is a poor structure. This was working fine for files in small numbers. But now, I have to deal with thousands of files which need to go through the same flow - benchmarks reveal that this takes ~ 1 day to finish processing. So, I'm planning to introduce some parallel processing to this flow. I want to modify my flow to achieve something like this:

```
                                    |
                                    |
                         +----------v----------+
                         |sftp-outbound-gateway|
                         |       "mget"        |
                         +----------+----------+
                                    | list of files
                                    |
                               +----v---+
                               |splitter|
                               +----+---+
         one thread             one | thread        ...
           +------------------------+---------------+--+--+--+--+
           | file                   | file          |  |  |  |  |
+---------------------+  +---------------------+
|     +----v----+     |  |     +----v----+     |
|     |decryptor|     |  |     |decryptor|     |
|     +----+----+     |  |     +----+----+     |
|          |          |  |          |          |
|    +-----v------+   |  |    +-----v------+   |   ...
|    |decompressor|   |  |    |decompressor|   |
|    +-----+------+   |  |    +-----+------+   |
|          |          |  |          |          |
|       +--v--+       |  |       +--v--+       |
|       | ... |       |  |       | ... |       |
|       +--+--+       |  |       +--+--+       |
+---------------------+  +---------------------+
           |                        |
      +----v----+              +----v----+
      |save file|              |save file|
      | to disk |              | to disk |
      +----+----+              +----+----+
           |                        |
           |                        |
```

For parallel processing, I output the files from the splitter on to a `ExecutorChannel` with a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

Some of the questions that I have:

1. I want all of the "FileProcessor" steps for one file to happen on the same thread, while multiple files are processed in parallel. How can I achieve this? 
   I saw from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42697846/9523462), that a `ExecutorChannel` to `MessageHandlerChain` flow would offer such functionality. But, some of the steps inside "FileProcessor" are optional (using `selector-expression` with routers to skip some of the steps) - ruling out using a `MessageHandlerChain`. I can rig up a couple of `MessageHandlerChain`s with `Filter`s inside, but this more or less becomes the approach mentioned in #2.
2. If #1 cannot be achieved, will changing all of the channel types starting from the splitter, from `DirectChannel` to `ExecutorChannel` help in introducing some parallelism? If yes, should I create a new `TaskExecutor` for each channel or can I reuse one `TaskExecutor` bean for all channels (I cannot set `scope="prototype"` on a `TaskExecutor` bean)?
3. In your opinion, which approach (#1 or #2) is better? Why?
4. If I perform global error handling, like the approach mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/error-handling.html), will the other files continue to process even if one file errors out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work as you need by using an `ExecutorChannel` as an input to the decrypter and leave all the rest as direct channels; the remaining flow does not have to be a chain, each component will run on one of the executor's threads.

You will need to be sure all your downstream components are thread-safe.

Error handling should remain as is; each sub flow is independent.

Comment: Thanks Gary. After splitting to the `ExecutorChannel`, will having `QueueChannel`s in the middle of the "FileProcessor" steps help as a buffer, while maintaining the desired flow shown in the question? I believe a `DirectChannel` blocks till the receiver is free to receive the message.

Comment: Help what? Once the work has been handed of to an executor thread, the remaining work will run on that thread - there is no benefit to adding a queue channel, you'd need another executor to poll that; you can control the concurrency with the pool size and overflow tasks will be queued in the executor.